# How would I be taxed by earning credits and selling items bought with them

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment

I was wondering about how I would go about putting this into my tax return. So I've recently started using a website that has a referral program, by promoting through this referral program I've amassed thousands in credits. I've bought electronics and resold them for a lesser value online.

When I report my taxes will I be taxed for receiving the credits and the money I made from selling the electronics? Or will it count as a loss since I'm buying the electronics and selling them at a lower price?

Comment: Do the credits have a cash equivalent value?  Could you get cash for them?

Comment: Yes they have cash value but you can't get cash for them you can only buy items with the credits.

Comment: @SPatrickApps Then they _don't_ have cash value.  It's like saying "this credit is worth a million dollars but you can only use it to buy this toaster."

Comment: @DStanley sounds like a nice toaster, how much would you take for that credit?

Comment: Did you buy the electronics only to sell them? Is this a business or a hobby?

Comment: @David Schwartz Yes I bought them only to sell them so I'm guessing that would qualify as a business

Comment: @SPatrickApps Check the IRS guidance for the difference between a business and a hobby. If you believe it qualifies as a business, file a schedule C. I believe the fair market value of the goods is income but also cost of goods sold. Your sales are ordinary business income. You will have to pay self-employment tax on your income. You'd probably be better off if you could characterize it as a hobby unless you can qualify for things like a home office deduction or if having to itemize deductions hurts you. (See updates to my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a business.  You go through a certain procedure.

The end result is you have a certain amount of USD, which you have "made" or "achieved" which you did not have previously.

You in fact "made" that much USD.

That's "income".

You are taxed on that much.  That's it.

(BTW, don't forget, you can deduct actual costs such as postage, use of internet and your home office etc.)

---

## *HOWEVER....*

I may be wrong.

It's very likly the IRS would simply tax you on the nominal (I guess retail) **value of the TV set**.

(The fact is that you then sold a used TV set on ebay is of no consequence to them.)

The fact is, through you efforts, you earned a TV set.

It's totally commonplace that when you do some work, you will be paid with a Good.  You simply pay tax as if the retail value.

So above I suggest you'll pay ta on the "final dollar amount you got on eBay" (say $1500).

I'm probably wrong - it's more likely you'll pay tax on the **full nominal retail value of the item**. (example, say, $2000).

---

Just for clarity, the idea that you have a ***loss*** here in some way is utterly absurd.

Comment: In the US, businesses are taxed on _income_, not cash on hand.

Comment: ?  the OP quite simply made - "got" if you will - a certain amount  of USD, from the overall transactions.    Could it be you saw the two words "in hand" and got muddled up with another concept?

Comment: OP uses credits to "buy" a TV that otherwise sells for $2,000. OP then sells that TV for $1,500. OP then has $1,500 in cash. You're saying the $1,500 is what should be taxed, which I believe is incorrect.

Comment: Hi DS! - It's hard to believe you're not familiar w/ the sort of semi-scam sites under discussion??  "Buy" is an English word with three letters, and it's great that the OP typed the word "b u y" in the question above!  Heh!  The OP fooled around on a pyramid site and (in short) "got" a TV which he sold on eBay.  OP "did some things" and in fact made, USD, 1500 bucks.  It is just - I don't know a less smarmy way to put this! - utterly inconceivable that the IRS would construe this as a "loss" in some way.   Because the OP clicked some buttons with P-Points or whatever it was.  (cont ..)

Comment: By all means, show me how I'm mistaken!  I want to know, really.

Comment: Come to think I wouldn't be surprised if the IRS would simply tax you on the nominal (I guess retail) value of the TV set.   After all, the fact that you then sold a used TV set on ebay is of no consequence to them.  The fact is, through you efforts, you ***earned a TV set***.  If one of my contracts gives me a $2000 TV set, I don't need to say what the IRS asks me to give the IRS!

Comment: Honestly I don't know exactly how it should be taxed (I am not a tax expert) but I'd be extremely surprised if the $1,500 in total was considered "income". That said, since I am admittedly not an expert I'll defer to those that are.

Comment: In the example you gave, there are three possibilities for how it's treated: an income of $1500, and income of $2000, or an income of $2000 but it's offset with a loss of $500. The third is of course equivalent to the first, but in that formulation, there is indeed a 
"loss".

Comment: Please, can you tell me why OP should pay taxes if he only sell for  $~1500-2000 if he doesn't have a business? Website and selling platforms like eBay will not even send a 1099-K if you sell under 20k or have less than 200 transactions. I don't know either why the $1500-2000 should be considered as an income even if he makes a profit.

Comment: @Gainz You are still _legally obligated_ to pay tax on income, even via selling stuff online. Just because they don't send you a 1099 doesn't mean that _legally_ you shouldn't pay tax. In reality, though, I suspect that _very few people_ actually report that as income.

Comment: @DStanley Thank you for the quick answer. Then I was mistaken, altough I know from a good source (someone working in taxes) that they won't (most of the time) take a look at it unless you receive a 1099-k or a similar document. That is why I tough it was considered the same as selling something on craiglist. Thanks again DStanley!

Comment: @Gainz Sure, the IRS won't investigate something they don't know about, but _legally_ you're still obligated to pay taxes. BTW, the same goes for craigslist, too :)

Comment: Note that both of my comments above only apply to items sold _for a profit_.

Answer (score 0):

To take Fattie's numbers, if you, as an individual, received a $2000 TV set, then you will be liable for taxes on $2000 in income. If you later sold it for $1500, then you would have a $500 loss, but the IRS won't let you deduct that loss if they consider it to be for personal use. So you'll have to clearly separate your business activity from your personal activity. How to do that in a manner that the IRS will accept is getting more into Law Stack Exchange territory.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "for personal use". He's selling the electronics, not using them. IRC 183 sets the rules for when they're deductible and this answer doesn't address them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I _think_ Accumulation is saying that the IRS's default position is that such reward schemes are "consumer orientated"... an "average Joe" gets enough points and is rewarded with (and potentially taxable on) a new TV. If they then decide to sell (2nd hand, below the "new" price), then so be it: that's not "tax relevant" – no different than selling your old TV when upgrading to a new one. On the other hand, If an "established business" bought goods which (for some reason) they then sold at a loss, that's a legitimate tax offset. [**cont**]

Comment: [**cont**] To have what the OP is doing count as the second case may involve having to jump though some IRS hoops (which they will probably then close if it happens often enough :-) )

Comment: @TripeHound Oh, well then that's almost certainly wrong. He's acquiring the property specifically to sell it, selling it new, and making a profit in the process. It's hard to imagine why his income wouldn't be taxable and his costs (necessary and reasonable to make that taxable profit) be deductible, per IRC 183 if nothing else.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree the income (the "new price") is probably taxable in either case; it's more a question of whether what the OP is doing is sufficiently "like a business" to be allowed to offset that income and reduce their tax burden. As you say (in the answer I hadn't noticed when I first commented): is it a hobby or a business.

Comment: @TripeHound Even if not, it's definitely sufficiently like a hobby. Again, see IRC 183. If your income is taxable and you're not an employee, your reasonable and necessary expenses to get that income are almost always deductible. And if he's regularly making a profit and running it like a business, then the IRS wants you to treat it as a business so that you have to pay self-employment taxes on that income.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Certainly, given the conditions set forth by the OP, they are making personal use of the electronics. My point is that the IRS doesn't make determinations based on whether the goods are for a business purpose, they make a determination based on whether the goods *have been established* as being for a business purpose. IRC 183 doesn't set rules for when costs are deductible, it sets rules for when they're *not*. If someone wins a prize on a game show valued at $10,000 and sells it for $7,000, can they claim only $7,000 of taxable income?

Comment: @Acccumulation If they make a business of going on game shows or pursue it as a hobby, absolutely! They just sold a new item for $7,000 for which their tax basis is $10,000 and the item was never for personal use. If they sold it for $11,000, the IRS would want taxes paid on $1,000, and they paid the taxes on the $10,000 for the item. The OP is not making personal use of the items he's selling -- he's acquiring them as inventory and selling them new.

Comment: What constitutes a "business" or "hobby"? Under what conditions would they *not* be able to claim their income is only $7000? Is anyone paying tax of $10000 in that circumstance simply not taking advantage of proper tax management?

Answer (score 0):

You either have a business or a hobby. There are several deciding factors, but key is whether you run it as a business and whether you have a reasonable expectation of making a profit. If you regularly profit, you can probably treat it a business and file a schedule C including your income and expenses.

As a business, you can probably treat the credits as having no cash value. That means you have no income when you get credits. However, when you trade these credits for electronics with a fair market value of $1,000, you have a $1,000 gain. If you then sell that piece of electronics for $800, you have a $200 loss.

If you don't meet the requirements to consider this a business, then it's a hobby. The rules for a hobby aren't quite as flexible. You must itemize your deductions, and you cannot take deductions that exceed expenses in any given year. The logic would still be the same, when you trade "worthless" coupons for something worth $1,000, you have a $1,000 hobby gain. When you sell that thing for $800, you have a $200 hobby loss. The gains are taxable, but you can deduct the losses.

In your case, you're probably better off if it's a hobby as that means your income isn't subject to self-employment tax. Check the IRS test carefully and see if you can defend that characterization.

**Update:**

Check the IRS guidance to see if it's a business or a hobby. Here are the differences:

Business: You file a schedule C. You may be able to take some deductions for things like a home office. You don't have to itemize your deductions. You will have to pay self-employment tax on your profits.

Hobby: You must itemize your deductions. You cannot deduct losses in excess of your income from the hobby. You do not have to pay self-employment tax on your profits.

Answer (score -1):

I would also say that it depends on the quantity of items you sold and the amount of money you made. Let say you have sell 4 items for a total of 900 USD, I would not necessarily declare taxes since it could just be a sale on eBay or Craiglist (just like selling a tv to your neighbour).

If you you sell a lot, then it is the same as a business and you will have to pay an amount of taxes depending on the state/country where you live.

In addition, for these electronic devices to count as a loss, you would probably have needed to buy them with real money. I'm not sure that the **credits** you used to buy these electronic devices count as a real dollar value (at least from a tax point of view).

Comment: This unfortunately amounts to no information, it seems.

Comment: This answer doesn't really make any sense. Why do you care what it "could just be" since we actually do know what it is? And your last paragraph makes no sense at all -- it's the sale that would be the loss, not the getting of the items for free. (For example, say my boss gives me a $1,000 TV for free. That's a $1,000 taxable gain (since I have no cost to offset it). Then if I sell it for $800, I definitely have a $200 loss.)

Comment: I was assuming that people who sell under 20k online or 200 transactions didn't have to pay taxes (since most of them are not). D Stanley corrected me on this. Also as for the loss I was still talking if he was not going to pay taxes, since where I live under 20k (selling online) the revenu agency just doesn't know that you are selling items online. I'm sorry english is not my first language and I am still learning it.